# why recv accept mort than expected number of bytes ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

When i call recv to receive exactly 7 bytes i recv more than bytes expected ?

I don't know how bufsize parameter work.

```
for i in range(data2[1]):
    try:
        tuple = envois.recv(7)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    if (tuple[-2:] != myport):
        tuples.append(tuple)

print("tuples : {x}".format(x = tuples))
last_msg = envois.recv(3)
envois.close()
return (last_msg,tuples)
```

Comment: Where's the evidence that you *did* receive more than 7 bytes?

Comment: Why are you calling a `bytes` object `tuple`? It's always a bad idea to hide the name of a built-in type like that, but this seems extra-misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `envois` is a socket, you will not receive more than the amount you specify. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)

> `socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])`
>
> Receive data from the socket. The return value is a bytes object representing the data received. The maximum amount of data to be received at once is specified by *bufsize*.

You should be able to `assert len(tuple) <= 7`

But, don't name a variable `tuple`. You will hide the builtin.